# Post Request is too large in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, salesforce, jmeter-plugins

Facing the issue while developing the performance script for salesforce application. The issue is, one of the apexremote post call is too large in size. Jmeter is getting hanged if i am trying to click that particular request. Even if I manage to enhance the post request somehow the cursor is not going to end of the line. Hence at the end of the line there is one CSRF which I am not able to correlate. This is only happening for only one apex post request. Because of this my orders are getting rejected while provisioning. I tried by increasing my heapsize in jmeter.bat file but no help.Searched in google but didn't find related queries. I tried the same thing with neoload and I was successfully access and enhanced that particular request. 
Has anyone experienced ever! How to resolve this.
Please HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the solution for the very big request for which meter is getting hanged. The best solution is to take the request from the html body of the view result tree listener for the recorded original one and paste in the payload of a new sampler. Then add it in appropriate place accordingly. We can also keep a raw request and make the correlation changes there itself instead of messing around in the big request payload.

Answer (score 1):

1.Basically for that you need to be Patience after clicking on the request and when the request populate properly copy that post data into `notepad++`for correlation purpose.

2.Or other solution is Open the .JMX directly into notepad and from there copy the post data into other notepad++ instance and form there with some manipulation you can do `correlation`.

3.Hope you already changed the property `"view.results.tree.max_size=0"` in `"jmeter.properties"` file because may be for next correlation you will get the message like **"Response data is to Large"**.

Comment: I copied the post body from the recorded script and did the enhancements in notepad++. But unfortunately I was not able to get the recorded response from server. Still getting 500 error. Not able to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced the same issue several times in past, so in that case just copy the complete post body and paste it into notepad++ and modify the content there instead of modifying in jmeter itself, then paste the content back to jmeter and execute it.

This will resolve your issue but have patience while clicking on http request to copy the post body because it'll take some time to open the request properly

Comment: I did the above. But unfortunately I am not able to resolve the issues. Still getting 500 error after correlating all the details. Not able to proceed further because of this single request and all my efforts are waste.

Comment: You might be doing some mistake while correlating the values and if you are not able to get the response properly in Jmeter (due to any reason) to correlate the values than you can navigate the application in browser with enabled developer tool (Press F12 on browser) and get the response from application to correalte

Comment: Yes. The issue is this is post call where salesforce is sending all the details  for provisioning which it had collected earlier like name, date etc. There were around 300 parameters I have correlated. Dont find any other parameters to be correlated except some random key value which are not there in any of the responses.